# UISearchBar and segues

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uisearchbar, detailview

Im using UITableViewController to manage data. When I click on the cell my program goes to another scene (let it be myDetailViewController). But i just added search bar (UISearchViewController) and search works great but when I click on the cell from the table with the filtered data nothing happens. But I need the program to go to myDetailViewController scene to view object details. How can i perform it?

Btw, for changing views (from a basic cells, not filtered) I'm using segues. And I'm also using this method:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"nameofmysegue"]) {
//some code to give some data to new controller;
    }
}
```

And when I'm using 
`tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath`:
without segues nothing happens at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to connect the segue to the view controller itself and not the tableview row.  Then in your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, you do a `[self performSegueWithIdentifier@"mySegueID"];`

Comment: Thank you very much. It really helped me out. Just used [self performSegueWithIdentifier@"mySegueID"]. But notice that now i connected not cell with detailview scene, but current scene with detailview scene.